# Would altering the cosmetic color of a Power Ring affect its function?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

A friend and I were looking into getting some Lantern Corps Rings from a really cool design site. During the discussion of which Corps to "join" my friend said he would probably fit well into Sinestro Corp but doesnt like the color yellow and joked that he would use a powder coat technique to recolor the ring. Which in turn made both of us wonder: if the rings are fueled by emotional energy would it still work correctly if you were to paint it or powder coat or electrolyze it? The yellow impurity in the green rings was in the main powerbattery on Oa, not a cosmetic paint job.

So, would recoloring the outside of a ring change the way it works?

Answer (score 4):

#### No, changing the physical color of the ring would not change the emotion required to use the ring, nor would it change the resultant color of the energy controlled by the ring.

- Each ring is specifically coded to a color and emotion and even disguising the ring would not change HOW it works or what color it produced.
- Depending on the color of the ring, it may induce physiological changes in the user of the ring which would not be altered by changing the color. **See: [Red Lanterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Lantern_Corps)**

> - Red Lanterns use red power rings, fueled by the rage of their users and those around them. Like other power rings, the ring covers the user in a protective aura which shields them from harm and enables flight, and can create "Hard Light" constructs. The power ring fires blasts of rage energy.
> - The user's blood is replaced by a form of corrosive, rage-energized blood. The user can regurgitate this blood. The blood has the effect of bursting into flames of rage; the flames are so potent that they will burn even in space.
> - The blood can melt through the constructs of other ring wielders, penetrate their personal force fields (sometimes burning them to death in the process), and corrupt their rings, depleting their energy at an accelerated rate.

- Power rings would likely resist any such artificial application of color upon their surfaces, as a failsafe to prevent anything from interfering with their function.